# command-line library build fails with linker error

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, graphviz

I am getting a *library not found error* building GraphViz current release (June 7 2012) with Xcode 4.3 using a script. I may have made mistakes updating build scripts from other people's successful recipes for the new location of Xcode4.3 and the developer tools in the Applications folder.

`ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o`

(doing this from memory so exact number on the CRT lib may be wrong)

Am also a little lost also how I would incorporate this into an Xcode build in the IDE. I am a very experienced programmer but having trouble finding my way around Xcode 4 at times. (Decades of Visual Studio et al).

I have copied the instructions from [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224827/build-static-graphviz-libraries-for-ios) and adapted

```
#!/bin/sh
# For iPhoneOS, see http://clang.llvm.org/ for options
export DEV_iOS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
# was /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDK_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
export COMPILER_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/usr/bin
export CC=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export CXX=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang++
export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -isysroot ${SDK_iOS}"
export CFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
export OBJCFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
export CXXFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"
export LD=${COMPILER_iOS}/ld
export CPP=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export AR=${COMPILER_iOS}/ar
export AS=${COMPILER_iOS}/as
export NM=${COMPILER_iOS}/nm
export CXXCPP="${COMPILER_iOS}/clang++"
export OBJC=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export RANLIB=${COMPILER_iOS}/ranlib

./configure \
--build=arm-apple-darwin11 \
--host=arm-apple-darwin11 \
--disable-dependency-tracking \
--enable-shared=no \
--enable-static=yes \
--enable-ltdl=no \
--enable-swig=no \
--enable-tcl=no \
--srcdir=${GVROOT} \
--with-codegens=no \
--with-cgraph=no \
--with-graph=yes \
--with-expat=no \
--with-fontconfig=no \
--with-freetype2=no \
--with-ipsepcola=yes \
--with-libgd=no \
--with-quartz=yes \
--with-visio=yes \
--with-x=no
```

Comment: It took me a couple months to get ramped up on Xcode after a number of years in VS.  Totally different paradigm plus it's not quite as polished (lots more crashes and various things you can't do like symbol lookups).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler normally uses crt1.o combined with crt[i/n].o and crt[begin/end].o to support the constructors and destructors (functions called before and after main and exit).

This error could be caused by this missing library file for the specific deployment target.

First, do some investigation, like:

1. list all your deployment targets:

   `ls -la /Developer/SDKs`
2. and find which crt1 libraries do you have for which environment

   `find /Developer/SDKs -name crt1\*`

You could see something like:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
```

So as you can see, crt1.10.6.o is missing for MacOSX10.5.

**Solution 1:**

You can solve that by creating the link to the missing file pointed to the other environment, or you could change your deployment target.
E.g.

```
ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/
```

---

Also this could be caused, that you have different gcc installed in your system. See:

`which gcc;`

`xcrun -find gcc;`

`brew list | grep gcc; brew list gcc47`

**Solution 2**

So when you're compiling using make, you can actually specify the right compiler by CC variable. E.g.

```
CC=/path/to/gcc-3.4 make
```

---

**Solution 3**

What you can also try is specifying the right target deployment environment variable for gcc, by executing the following lines:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib
```

If this works, then you can add above lines to your shell profile (~/.profile) to make the change permanent.

---

**How to test**

Create the example `conftest.c` file with the following code:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  yes;
#endif
```

And try to compile it via:

```
gcc conftest.c
cc conftest.c
cc conftest.cc conftest.c
```

**Troubleshooting**

To see which exactly what file is missing, try to debug it using dtruss, e.g.:

```
sudo dtruss -f gcc conftest.c 2>/dev/stdout | grep crt
```

You should see something like:

```
12426/0xb4e3b:  stat64("/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/crt1.10.6.o\0", 0x7FFF5FBFE780, 0xB)        = -1 Err#2
```

So once you found the missing file, then you can follow by the first solution by linking the missing file from existing location (e.g. `locate crt1.10.6.o`). If you will have other missing symbols, then try another file (check the architecture before by: `` file `locate crt1.10.6.o` ``).

E.g.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/crt1.10.6.o
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64/crt1.10.6.o
```

---

**Related**

[Error in xcode project: ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365211/error-in-xcode-project-ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt1-10-6-o#comment22989447_1365211)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly this is what fixed the library not found problem.

```
CFLAGS="$(OTHER_CFLAGS) -miphoneos-version-min=5.0"
LDFLAGS="$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) --miphoneos-version-min=5.0"
```

To link this to Xcode, under Build Settings then Header and Library search paths you need to add the paths to the built versions of the library and the header.

You can add the build script as part of your Xcode project, but I haven't had success with this, plus you should only need to build it once per version, so putting the time into anything other than a build script doesn't have much return.

If you decide to put the script in your project anyway (good luck!), then go to the build phases tab, add a build phase of type "Run Script" and paste your script there.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't use Xcode to build the library, I built it using a script and then linked it to my project.

Comment: thanks, will try it tonight (I'm at the day job waiting for a VS build  right now)